# Using _middleware in next-auth redirects to favicon.ico

Tags: next.js, next-auth

To protect all pages on the site without authorization, I use _middleware.js.
./pages/_middleware.js

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
```

When I go to the site without authorization, I am redirected to the login form. But after I fill it out and log in, it redirects me to http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico
Why on favicon.ico I can't understand. Maybe someone will explain.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what causes this but setting a redirect callback in NextAuthOptions seems to solve it.

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
...
callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
       return baseUrl;
    },
  }
};
```